# git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) - colleges cannot see changes?

Tags: git

I see the error (I am using latest tortoise git on with bit bucket server)

```
 git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)
```

with the details below
The order of thinks I am doing

1. my repository is probably not up to date
2. I do commit and push to master
3. I get the below error code  git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)
4. I do git pull getting all recent changes
5. then I try to commit and push to master again but then I get a message "**No files were changed or added since the last commit**"
   When my team mates try to pull the changes - they don't see my file changes

How to fix this?

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" master:master

<truncated>
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@bitbucket<truncated>'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
 hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (6547 ms @ 2/27/2018 12:14:57 PM)
```

Comment: How about researching what the error message suggest? You cannot push your commit because someone else pushed work that would be discarded.

Comment: I understand, but this is an weird case, I am pulling changes, then cannot commit and colleges cannot see changes?

Comment: If no conflicts occur during the merge you don't have to commit yourself. What exactly happens when you `git pull`?

Comment: it pulls cleanly, there is no conflict